# Making an HTTPS site using Django

Tags: python, django, https

I'm using Django to build a site and I want one part of my site to be in HTTPS.

In my settings.py file, I have

`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`

In my wsgi.py file, I have `os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"`

Then in my views.py for the part of the site I'm working on, I'm using a decorator to force everything to be redirected to https.

```
def secure_required(view_func):
    def _wrapped_view_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_secure():
            if getattr(settings, 'HTTPS_SUPPORT', True):
                request_url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
                secure_url = request_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(secure_url)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view_func
```

However, when I try to load the page on my localhost, the page doesn't load and I just get an error that says "This webpage is not available." What am I missing to enable HTTPS for my website?

The webserver log shows this:

```
13:38:22 web.1     | 2013-08-02 13:38:22 [48421] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:48423) 
13:38:22 web.1     | 2013-08-02 13:38:22 [48421] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:48423)
13:38:22 web.1     | 2013-08-02 13:38:22 [48444] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 48444
```

Comment: What does the webserver error log say?

Comment: @dan-klasson updated the question to show webserver log

Comment: so it seems like when i try https:// on localhost it never loads, but when I load the actual site with https:// it works. Does https not load on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out https doesn't work on localhost, which I didn't know before.